# How to stop IntelliJ from placing semicolons after an auto-completion?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

so this is annoying me because I use tab to leave brackets etc and when I use auto-complete and a semicolon is being placed after the bracket this happens:

https://streamable.com/i9as2

as you can see in the first statement I'm having problems "jumping" over the semicolon while when I dont use the auto-completion in the second statement (and don't get the semicolon automatically) it's way easier to navigate through it with tab. I know that there is the shift-enter shortcut but I don't really want to develop a habbit of using it so often because I can imagine trying to do that when working with my other IDE's can become quite annoying. I searched through the options but did not find any option do disable that behavior. Does anyone know a way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Second Tab press should jump after the semicolon, I've [created a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211180) for that.

It's already fixed and the fix will be available starting from 2019.2 IDE version.