# How to tab past a semicolon with IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am running `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.3 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-191.7479.19`, on a Macbook Pro with `Mac OS Mojave v10.14.6`

I know it is possible to tab past (jump outside) brackets and quotes within IntelliJ, as the picture states below.

[image]

But how do you do the same to get past the semicolon at the end? An answer for `Mac` and `Windows` would be helpful. Here is what happens now:

```java
Class newClass = myMethod.getNewClass();

//if you tab after Class() you get the following

Class newClass = myMethod.getNewClass()    ;
```

Comment: This was fixed in 2019.2: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-211180, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55721338/104891. Did you try with the current IDE version?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Wow. They just came out with 2019.2 three days ago huh. Let me get the newest version and try it out.

Comment: @CrazyCoder what setting is this? I upgraded to 2019.2 but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: It's the same setting, notice the feature description: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2019.2/settings-smart-keys.html — Note that this only works on initial typing: during subsequent editing, pressing Tab inside brackets/quotes will insert the Tab character..

Comment: @CrazyCoder this does not work. On the initial method creation I still get a tab between the last `)` and the `;`. Your link says nothing about tabing past the semicolon as well as brackets. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the short video and the sample file attached. Note that this feature works only when `;` is inserted via the completion. It's not clear how you get the caret before the semicolon when using the code completion: `Class newClass = myMethod.getNewClass()|;`.